# How to use @fluentui/react-icons

Tags: reactjs, icons, fluent, webpack-5, fluentui-react

Is there any better way to use @fluentui/react-icons

I am importing icons below way.

```
import { Home20Regular } from '@fluentui/react-icons'
```

I am expecting it should download only one Icon during build using treeshaking
But looks like it is downloading whole packages and increase the bundle size.
[memory consumtion for @fluentui/react-icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dApUw.png)

I am expecting it should download the icons I am using in my code base instead of whole package

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with the following issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/25989

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and was able to resolve the treeshaking issue by upgrading my version of webpack to 5.88.2 and @fluentui/react-icons to 2.0.215

Answer (score 0):

I followed the comment from https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui-system-icons/issues/619#issuecomment-1646525481

I was using `"module": "commonjs"` in my tsconfig.json.

I changed it to:

```
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

and it changed my webpack bundle size from 14MB down to 1.7MB.